# Moved Opencart from live server to local MAMP environment and now the English language file for admin wont load

Tags: php, mysql, apache, opencart, mamp

I just moved my website hanginsouth.com to a local dev environment using MAMP on my Mac.  The site works fine until I go to the admin panel where I receive the following error

Notice:

> Error: Could not load language english! in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hanginsouth/system/library/language.php on
>   line 40

It appears `language.php` is trying to access the file

`admin/language/english/english.php`

which is in fact there with the permission `r-- r-- r--`

For some reason it can not load the file and is throwing an error.  Does anyone know why this could be happening?